# Mount local directory not working on DockerFile

Tags: docker, jmeter, dockerfile

Mount to local directory is giving error On running below command
docker build -t Testing:latest .

Error:

> failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: dockerfile parse error line 20: Missing a value on flag: mount

DockerFile Code:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/docker/library/ubuntu:focal

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ENV TZ=America/New_York

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y apt-utils \
    build-essential \
    openjdk-8-jdk \
    zip \
    && apt-get clean
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y dos2unix

WORKDIR /app
COPY apache-jmeter-5.4 ./apache-jmeter-5.4
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN ["chmod", "a+x", "/entrypoint.sh"]
RUN ["chmod", "a+x", "./apache-jmeter-5.4/bin/jmeter.sh"]  
RUN dos2unix /entrypoint.sh && apt-get --purge remove -y dos2unix && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN --mount type=bind,source="C:/Users/PerfTest/Tests/apache-jmeter-5.4/bin/",target="/app/apache-jmeter-5.4/bin/"
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Comment: Mount is to run the script from my local directory.

Comment: On the one hand, it looks like you're missing an `=` sign; `--mount=type=...` is the usual syntax.  On the other, you already `COPY`ed JMeter into the image into a previous step, and it doesn't seem like this `RUN` has an actual command to run.  Can you just delete this `RUN` line entirely?